# Ставится ли запятая в "При условии выбора методов маршрутизации(,) эффективных в различных условиях."?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Ставится ли запятая в "При условии выбора методов маршрутизации(,) эффективных в различных условиях."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставится. Обособленное определение, выраженное прилагательным с зависимыми словами, стоит после определяемого слова.

Comment: @ Людмила,разве это опредилительный оборот? При условии - обстоятельственный оборот.

Comment: При условии выбора методов(каких?),эффективных в различных условиях.